# qmake no bluetooth

Tags: qt, qtbluetooth

I Have a project that uses QT Bluetooth and i managed to compile it up until today
Today when calling QMake I get

```
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: bluetooth
```

the .pro file looks something like this:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Thu Sep 29 10:34:51 2016
######################################################################

QT += bluetooth
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += debug

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = build/ankioverdrive
#INCLUDEPATH += .

LIBS += -lmosquittopp

LIBS += -L/usr/lib

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/

# Input
SOURCES += some/paths/to/files.cpp \

HEADERS += \
    some/paths/to/files.h \
```

running `qmake --version` which seemd to be the problem for some before gave me

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I'm on Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install qtconnectivity5-dev`

Comment: it states that it is allready installed

Comment: Do you have several Qt installed? It seems to me that you have several Qt installed, because in your .pro points at the top: `... generated by qmake (3.0) ...` and in with qmake --version you get: `QMake version 3.1`

Comment: might actually be the case but i'm not sure how to check that

Comment: How have you installed Qt?

Comment: thats only the case because i used a opensourceproject from github that had made the .pro, instead of me

Comment: Ah OK I understand

Comment: that was some time back i did install it half a year ago when it worked. And it worked up untill today. Not sure in which way i did it anymore

Comment: didn't work either

Comment: but still thank you
Your Answers helped me to find a sollution

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Problem by reinstalling Qt via the qt-unified install tool for linux, and running the qmake file in that installPath

```
PathToInstallation/version/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

this worked

Comment: LOL, You had 2 Qt installed, one the one that used the Qt installer and the other one that comes natively in Kubuntu, and with the apt-get command you had installed in the second one and you are using in the qt-creator the first one. :-)

Comment: seemed like it
But i still don't know what did break my installation to make i unable to compile